# In Eclipse, automaticly republish when struts-config.xml is edited

Tags: eclipse, struts-1

When the **web.xml** file is edited. in Eclipse, the project will be republished and restarted, how do I let this behaviour also apply to when the **struts-config.xml** file is edited?

Comment: AFAIK (and working in my environment) as long as the auto-publish checkbox is checked eclipse will publish **any** changes to the server. Maybe it is just too fast to see!? Have you verified that the version on the server is the 'old' one?

Comment: yes, it really republished ,but not restart the application, so I have to manually restart the application, when strusts config edited. but when I edit web.xml, it republish and restart the application.

Comment: Just a hint: you could give a try to JRebel (the trial is free) and that can prevent those necessary redeploys by updating the configs automatically. Sometimes it messes up line numbers though.